# PHP Contact Form Not Being Received In Email

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I know there is a few of these posts already up, and I read through them, but was unable to find the solution to my problem. The PHP and HTML looks good so I am not exactly sure why I am not receiving any email from the submitted contact form.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

$Fname = $_POST ['Fname'];
$Lname = $_POST ['Lname'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];

$to = 'myName@mywebsite.com';
$subject = 'Contact From My Website';
$msg = " First Name: $Fname/n" .
"Last Name: $Lname/n" .
"Email: $email/n" .
"Message: $message";

mail ($to, $subject, $msg,"From: " . $Fname . $Lname);

$confirm = "Thank you for contacting us! Please allow 48 hours for a representative to respond. Click <a href='contact.php'>here</a> to return to the previous page.";

?>
```

And here is the HTML form code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="send.php">
                <tr>
                    <label><td width="160px" class="labels">First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="input"><input type="text" name="Fname" id="Fname"/></td>
                    </label>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <label><td class="labels">Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="input"><input type="text" name="Lname" id="Lname"/></td>
                    </label>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <label><td class="labels">Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="input"><input type="email" name="email" id="email"/></td>
                    </label>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <label><td class="labels">Message:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="input"><textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></td>
                    </label>                                    
                </tr>
                <tr>                        
                    <td class="labels"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated

Comment: First of all `/n` is invalid. They all need to be `\n`. Change all your `/n` to `\n` then try it again.

Comment: Second, I'm doubting your mail headers.

Comment: Shouldn't your from-header include an email adress? have you access to the smtp-servers logs?

Comment: @PugganSe That's why I doubted the OP's headers.

Comment: Read up on the `mail( )` function and its proper use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @OP See my answer below, it's been tested and working.

Comment: And please click the little checkmark found under the up-down arrows to accept my answer as the solution, it will turn **green**. It is working now. If you do not, then it will remain as being **"unanswered"**. cheers

Comment: can the server send mail outside of php? It might not be a code problem, rather a server problem.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

### There were many errors.

Improper use of `\n`, `mail()` headers and trying to `echo` a success message at the end.

**Here is a tested and working mail handler script.**

**NOTE**: I added an `if{isset` condition.

Change `email@example.com` with your own E-mail address.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

$Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
$Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "email@example.com"; // <<< change this to your own E-mail address
$subject = "Contact From My Website";
$msg = "First Name: $Fname\n" . "Last Name: $Lname\n" . "Email: $email\n" . "Message: $message";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

echo "Thank you for contacting us! Please allow 48 hours for a representative to respond. Click <a href='contact.php'>here</a> to return to the previous page.";

?>
```

---

---

### Supplement

Please read up on the `mail( )` function and its proper use of headers by visiting:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**

There are plenty of examples on that page.

One **major error** is your use of `/n` and all need to be changed to `\n` if anything.

That alone will ultimately make your handler **fail**.

Answer (score 0):

"From" should not include the name, instead it should include the from email address.

So, instead of

```
"From: " . $Fname . $Lname
```

You should be doing

```
"From: ". $myEmail
```

Here's a valid header from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

I guess Puggan and Fred get credit for this answer as-well, since they have posted out the obvious but not yet made it an answer.

You should also make sure that the id of the message labels match to $_POST['msg'], so you should not be using 'msg' in one place and 'message' in another.

FYI: skip the spaces ' ' between the function name and the parameter arguments. i.e.

```
$_POST ['stuff'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
$headers = "From:" . $Fname . $Lname;
```

and use this:

```
mail ($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```